# Invariant under isometric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am not familiar with the formal compute about the invariant under diffeomorphism (isometric),so I want a detail example. For example,$M,N$ are Riemannian manifolds, $\Phi :M\rightarrow N$ is diffeomorphism.How to formally show 
$$
\int_MR(\Phi^*g_{ij}) dV(\Phi^*g_{ij})=\int_N R(g_{ij})dV(g_{ij})
$$

I always don't know how to compute the integration,when the metric and manifold be changed.So, I really want a detail example to imitate.

Comment: This is just change of coordinates. You can look in Lee's smooth manifolds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change of variable implies that $$ \int_NRdV(g)=\int_M R\circ f
dV(f^\ast g) $$ where $f: M\rightarrow (N,g)$

Hence we must show that $ R(g,f(x))=R(f^\ast g,x) $ But scalar
curvature is invariant under isometry so that this is clear.